# Japanese characters cannot be seen in Spring Batch Admin UI

Tags: spring-batch-admin

Japanese characters cannot be seen in Spring Batch Admin UI.
My code is as the following:

```
public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution stepContribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {  
stepContribution.setExitStatus(new ExitStatus("SKIPPED", "例パラメータ does not exist."));  
}
```

But it displayed `Exit Message` as the following:
[image: Japanese characters cannot be displayed]
How can I do to display the japanese characters in Spring Batch Admin UI??
I used SpringBatchAdmin 1.0.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I set the `UTF-8 encoding` in freemarker template, Japanese character can be shown in Spring Batch Admin UI.
There are 2 ways to solve the problem:

1. Using SpringBatchAdmin 1.2.2 and above because I found that the problem had already fixed on SpringBatchAdmin 1.2.2.
2. Overriding the `resources-context.xml` under `/META-INF/spring/batch/servlet/resources/` of `spring-batch-admin-resources-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar`

Since the first way is not ok for me, I use the second way.
I create an xml file under `/META-INF/spring/batch/servlet/override/` to override the `resources-context.xml`.
I add the `contentType` property in `standard` bean.
Here is the snippet of newly created xml file:

```
<bean id="standard" parent="parentLayout">
    <property name="url" value="/layouts/standard.ftl" />
    <property name="contentType" value="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <property name="attributes">
        <props merge="true">
            <prop key="body">/layouts/home.ftl</prop>
            <!-- Matches the prefix of the servlet mapping in web.xml -->
            <prop key="servletPath">#{resourceService.servletPath}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Hope this will help the others also. :)